# Strange crash with app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-ndk

Recently my app crashes really strange, If I start the app it gives a white screen for a second or 10 and than it stops working.

logcat gives the following error but I don't understand it, can you guys help me ?

Error log too large, please look at it at pastebin:
[Error log](http://pastebin.com/QTYUpp3G)

EDIT------------------

I think this piece of code generates the error, it started after I added it:
Im only not sure what the error is, i don't understand the logcat output

```
{
    Calendar cal = loadCurrentCalendar();
    long currentMil = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    int hourI = cal.HOUR_OF_DAY;

    while (hourI <19)
    {
        currentMil = currentMil + ONE_HOUR;
        hourI ++;
    }
    setSleepMil(currentMil + SLEEP_TIME); // TODO werkt dit ? + SLEEP_TIME stond hier achter currentMil
    return getSleepMil();
}

public int hourPassedSleepCur(long sleepMil)
{
    Calendar cal = loadCurrentCalendar();
    long currentMil = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    hoursPassed = 0;

   while (sleepMil < currentMil)
    {
        hoursPassed ++;
        setSleepMil(getSleepMil()+ ONE_HOUR);
    }
    return hoursPassed;
}
```

}

EDIT 2-------------------------------------------

Im accessing it with this piece of code witch runs in a thread that checks every few milisec

```
public void checkSleepyTime()
{
    currentCalendar = timeHelper.loadCurrentCalendar();

    int hour = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int daypart = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    if (hour >= 20 && daypart == 1 || hour < 6 && daypart == 0)
    {
        foodButton.setText("ZZzz");
        prefs.edit().remove("foodTime").commit();
        buddy.setSleeping(true);
    }
    else
    {
        buddy.setFoodLevel(buddy.getFoodLevel() - timeHelper.hourPassedSleepCur(loadNextSleepyTime()));
       // buttonTest.setText(timeHelper.hourPassedSleepCur(getNextSleepyTime()));
        saveNextSleepyTime();
        sleepTimeView.setText("sleepy at: " + String.valueOf(loadNextSleepyTime()));
        foodButton.setText("Awake");
        buddy.setSleeping(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your error from logcat directly on your post and format it, it will be easier than downloading a file :)

Comment: More info about app. Are you using jni, android api version, etc?

Comment: I'm using API 16 and running on a Virtual android with API 22

Comment: I think the problem is in the while loop and sleep statement , Cant help ,because I do not know what are you doing in this

Comment: I added the piece of code in  witch i access the methods